# Bind XSD element to a Java implementation?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, mule

I would like to know how to bind an XML tag in a certain namespace to some implementation in Java e.g. the way Mule does with the tags defined in it's various XSD files. Is it related/done with JAXB or is that just for mapping Java beans to XML?

Regards Ola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my article on JAXB and namespaces:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

With JAXB you can choose the granularity at which namespace information is provided:

- At the package level using @XmlSchema
- At the type level using @XmlType
- At the field/property level using @XmlElement and @XmlAttribute

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understad your question. Are you asking about unmarshalling ?

If so try use sth like below:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("some.package");
Unmarshaller u = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
XMLInputFactory inFac = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader reader = inFac.createXMLStreamReader(this.getClass().
                              getResourceAsStream("inputFile.xml"));
JAXBElement<Mule> freestyleElement = u.unmarshal(reader,Mule.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and suggestions but it's more about binding functionality to a tag/element rather than marshaling data back and forth. Taking Mule as an example there are a set of tags for different transformations, e.g. <xslt-transformation .../> which binds to a Java class implementing a common interface AbstractTransformer and of course the actual XSLT transformation code. What I don't understand is how the tag is bound to the actual Java implementation.

Comment: To clarify a bit more, there is a standard transformer in Mule which have the tag:

<object-to-string-transformer name="ToString"/>

that is implemented in a class ObjectToStringTransformer. The core of my question is, how is the tag bound to the implementing class? I suspect that the XSD is involved somehow since without refereing to the relevant XSD in the document the tag is undefined but I don't know.

There is a lot of articles how to marshall/unmarshall data between Java and XML but that's for data. I have not yet found anything about binding tag to an implementation as desc. above.